# Javascript, how to use regex to parse string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string with multiple `{{Start:SomeName}}` and I need to repalce it with
`<div data-name="SomeName"></div>` and `{{End:SomeName}}` to `</div>`

I was trying use replace like this `replace("{{Start:", '<div data-name="');` but this works only for start part.. maybe some regex, but I don't know how.

I'll be greatful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With something as structured as your string, it's probably easier to just take a `slice()` and `split()` into variables:

```js
let s = "{{Start:SomeName}}"
let [side, name] = s.slice(2, -2).split(':')
let tag = `<div data-name="${name}"></div>`
console.log(tag)
```

If you have several of these, you can use a regex to find them all in `replace()` and use the above idea in the replacer function passed to `replace()` to calculate the replaced value:

```js
let s = "Some text {{Start:SomeName}} some other text {{End:SomeName}}{{Start:SomeName}}more{{End:SomeName}}"

let n = s.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, (match, s) => {
    let [side, name] = s.split(':')
    if (side === "Start") return `<div data-name="${name}">`
    else if (side === "End") return '</div>'

})


console.log(n)
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the exact string you are dealing with. Is it multiple of just these tags? Or is there other text interwoven?

Comment: let s = "{{Start:SomeName}}{{Start:SomeName}} {{End:SomeName}} {{End:SomeName}} " for example

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```js
const input = '{{Start:SomeName}}{{Start:SomeName}} {{End:SomeName}} {{End:SomeName}}'

const result = input.replace(/{{(.+?):(.+?)}}/g, '<div data-name="$2"></div>')
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something along these lines

```js
const str = '{{Start:SomeName}} hello {{End:SomeName}} {{Start:AnotherName}} world {{End:AnotherName}}';

const replaced = str.replace(/{{Start:(\w+)}}(.*){{End:(\1)}}/g, (_, name, content) => {
    return `<div data-name="${name}">${content}</div>`;
});

console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
result = "{{Start:SomeName}}{{Start:SomeName}} {{End:SomeName}} {{End:SomeName}} ".replace(/{{Start:(\w+)}}|{{End:(\w+)}}/g,(...a)=>{
    if(a[1]){
  return `<div data-name="${a[1]}">`
    }
 else{
  return `</div>`
    }
 
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RegEx like bellow

```js
var re = /\{\{Start:(.*)\}\}(.*)\{\{End:(.*)\}\}/g; 
var chaine = "{{Start:SomeName}}Hello World{{End:SomeName}}"

var output = chaine.replace(re,"<div date-name='$1'>$2</div>");

console.log(output)
```

The first parentheses in the regex capture the name which will be set as the value of attribute `data-name` and the second catch the content which is enclose inside the `START` block and `END` block,

like the regex has capturing parentheses all reference to string which match each capturing parentheses will be accessible by using `$` sign follow by the position of the parentheses